# tor starts on boot automatically

Tags: tor

when i boot ubuntu,tor starts automatically
i tried to delete its symbolic link from rc5.d directory 
but still its running from boot 
Ubuntu uses runlevel 5 by default so why tor should start again?
if i start run level3 and tor starts automatically its reasonable because i didn't deleted tor symbolic link (S01tor) from it
any idea how to stop it?

[image: like this one]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether tor is enabled or not on boot by executing following command on terminal.

```
sudo systemctl status tor.service
```

If it enabled on boot, you can disable it.

```
sudo systemctl disable tor.service
```